# Adding a Co-administrator via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, subscription, administrator

I know how to add a co-administrator via the portal, but need a way to add it via PowerShell.

I need this method as I have lost access to the login id, but have the publish setting file so can administrator my virtual machines.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can't. Azure PowerShell Cmdlets are essentially wrapper over [`Azure Service Management API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx) and currently the API does not expose any method to add co-admins programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Azure have rolled out Roll Based Access Control which will allow you to automate the adding of new admins to your Azure Subscription. Intro here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/

You would add a new user as an Owner at the Subscription scope. These operations are available using both [PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-powershell/) and [REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn906885.aspx)

Comment: Yes, however (at this time) you still cannot grant co-admin permissions to a user in order to access V1 resources in the V1 portal, or through ASM PowerShell. That is, RBAC permissions don't apply to the V1 stack, only ARM & Graph API.