# Azure still haven't provide REST API for Adding co-admin Right?

Tags: azure

I can list all my admin/co-admin eamail accounts by :
[List Subscription User Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn469420.aspx)
But I didn't found any API for adding a eamail account to Azure co-admins.
Does this API exist?

Comment: That's correct. Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286524/adding-a-co-administrator-via-the-powershell/23287261#23287261.

Comment: @GauravMantri - you should also tag this question as a duplicate.